# Automatic float css only?

Tags: html, css, css-float, multiple-columns, box

I was thinking of having this kind of layout:
[Layout with 2 columns and boxes, that automatically fit in free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdw2w.png)

Is there a ***css only*** solution for that?

My current html, which i generate with php:

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header"><h1>Header blablablaaa</h1></div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header"><h2>Sub-Header1</h2></div>
    <div class="box-text"><p>Text1</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header"><h2>Sub-Header2</h2></div>
    <div class="box-text"><p>Text2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header"><h2>Sub-Header3</h2></div>
    <div class="box-text"><p>Text3</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a css thing and need some more modification in your HTML.
if you want two dis to work free without affecting its right/left height you need to seperate them in different divs

This is something what similar to your requiremets, what you need to do is for any extra style you need to add your desired css

```html
<style>
.left_side, .right_side{ width:45%; float:left;}
.left_side{ margin-right: 10px;}
.box { border: 2px solid black; width:100%; float:left; margin: 5px;}
.a1 { min-height:150px;}
.a2 { min-height:200px;}
.a3 { min-height:250px;}
.a4 { min-height:150px;}
</style>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="header"><h1>Header blablablaaa</h1></div>
        <div class="left_side">
          <div class="box a1">
           <div class="box-header"><h2>Sub-Header1</h2></div>
            <div class="box-text"><p>Text1</p></div>
           </div>
           <div class="box a2">
             <div class="box-header"><h2>Sub-Header2</h2></div>
             <div class="box-text"><p>Text2</p></div>
           </div>
       </div>
      <div class="right_side">
      <div class="box a3">
        <div class="box-header"><h2>Sub-Header3</h2></div>
        <div class="box-text"><p>Text3</p></div>
      </div>
 <div class="box ai4">
        <div class="box-header"><h2>Sub-Header4</h2></div>
        <div class="box-text"><p>Text3</p></div>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what i meant to do! Thanks alot <3

Comment: Do you also have an idea how to make it so on mobile devices on non-landscape they are in 1 column?

Comment: for mobile devices and non-landscape devices use @media css. probebly https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ will help you

Comment: Well.. Yea, but there are 2 `div`s, so i dont think i could put them into each other / combine them into one right? Putting the one below the other would work anyways.